# How to access both contexts of "this" in a callback function?

Tags: javascript, node.js

```js
class MyExampleClass {
    constructor(port, service) {
        this.port = port;
        this.service = service;
        this.app = require('express')();
        this.http = require('http').createServer(this.app);
    }

    onListening() {
        // Current result: 'listening on port NaN for undefined'
        // Desired result: 'listening on port 3000 for test' (I want to CHANGE this behavior)
        console.log('listening on port %d for %s', this.port, this.service);

        // Current result: 'class: Server'
        // Desired result: 'class: Server' (I want to KEEP this behavior)
        console.log('class: ' + this.constructor.name);
    }

    start() {
        this.http.listen(this.port, this.onListening);
    }
}

const example = new MyExampleClass(3000, 'test');
example.start();
```

As stated in the comments of the `onListening` method, I want to access both the context of the instance of `MyExampleClass` and the callback instance of `Server` created by `createServer`.

Comment: A common technique is to put ```const self=this``` somewhere before the context switch and using self instead of this when referencing the other context

Comment: @DovRine how would I do that cleanly if I have my callback as a separate method? Would I have to pass `self` in as another parameter to `onListening` or is there a better way so as not to alter the method signature?

Comment: I posted an answer that might help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bind `this.onListening` in the constructor to preserve the `this` context inside `onListening`.

You can't have `this` point to 2 different contexts so you will have to access the `Server` instance through `this.http`.

```
class MyExampleClass {
    constructor(port, service) {
        this.port = port;
        this.service = service;
        this.app = require('express')();
        this.http = require('http').createServer(this.app);

        this.onListening = this.onListening.bind(this);
    }

    onListening() {
        console.log('listening on port %d for %s', this.port, this.service);
        console.log('class: ' + this.http.constructor.name);
    }

    start() {
        this.http.listen(this.port, this.onListening);
    }
}

const example = new MyExampleClass(3000, 'test');
example.start();
```

Comment: The first call to `log` in `onListening` has the desired behavior, but not the second call to `log`. The second call now logs `class: MyExampleClass`.

Comment: @Hank then change `this.constructor.name` to `this.http.constructor.name`

Comment: what do you expect to be printed out in the second log? this solution is correct, `constructor.name` is the name of the class

Comment: @AdamKosmala the question lists the desired and actual outputs that are printed.

Comment: @Hank You can't have `this` point to 2 different contexts, use `this.http.constructor.name` to access the Server instance

Comment: @Hank, ok, with the updated question it makes sense

Comment: @AdamKosmala Yes i thought the same thing at first

Answer (score 2):

Just use `bind(this)` on your callback reference like this `this.http.listen(this.port, this.onListening.bind(this));`

following the code will work

```
class ExampleServer {
    constructor(port, service) {
        this.port = port;
        this.service = service;
        this.app = require('express')();
        this.http = require('http').createServer(this.app);
    }

    onListening() {
        // I want to access the context for the instance of `ExampleServer`, but `this` is the context for the instance of `Server` created by `createServer`.
        console.log('listening on port %d for %s', this.port, this.service);

        // I want to also still be able to access the context for the instance of `Server` created by `createServer`, which is what the below is already doing.
        console.log(this.http.constructor);
    }

    start() {
        this.http.listen(this.port, this.onListening.bind(this));
    }
}

const server = new ExampleServer(3000, 'test');
server.start();
```

Comment: This doesn't give me the desired behavior that I want. See my edit to the question.

Answer (score 2):

Use arrow functions

```
class ExampleServer {
  constructor (port, service) {
    this.port = port
    this.service = service
    this.app = require('express')()
    this.http = require('http').createServer(this.app)
  }

  onListening = () => {
    console.log('listening on port %d for %s', this.port, this.service)
  }

  start = () => {
    this.http.listen(this.port, this.onListening)
  }
}

const server = new ExampleServer(3000, 'test')
server.start()
```

Comment: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token =`

Answer (score -4):

How about something like this?

```
onListening(server=null) {
   const self = this;
        // I want to access the context for the instance of `ExampleServer`, but `this` is the context for the instance of `Server` created by `createServer`.
       if(server){
            console.log('listening on port %d for %s', server.port, server.service);
       }
        // I want to also still be able to access the context for the instance of `Server` created by `createServer`, which is what the below is already doing.
        console.log(self);
    }
```

Comment: This is bad design, for instance you can look @krishna's answer to solve it in a more elegant way.

Comment: @AlejandroGarciaAnglada: This is not bad design. See: Javascript var self = this; vs. .bind (https://gist.github.com/jashmenn/b306add36d3e6f0f6483)

Comment: It's bad design in a sense that it just doesn't work. If you set `self = this` in the same context where you use `self`, it's exactly equivalent to just using `this` directly. The `self = this` must be done earlier, where the value of `this` is guaranteed to be what you want.

Comment: @JJJ: My mistake. You are correct. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Correct, I was meaning what @JJJ said.